# Sample adjacent textures in openGL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am implementing a morphological grayscale erosion in shader language to get the outlines of a labelled image:

[image: Labelled image]

The shader code looks like this:

```
#version 430
in vec2 texCoords;
out vec4 outColor;

uniform isampler2D samplerTex;
ivec2 offsets[4] = ivec2[](ivec2(0, -1), ivec2(-1, 0), ivec2(1, 0), ivec2(0, 1));

void main()
{
    ivec2 texsize = textureSize(samplerTex, 0);
    ivec2 outcoords = ivec2(texCoords * texsize);
    uint pixel = texelFetch(samplerTex, outcoords, 0).x;
    if (pixel == 0)
        discard;

    uint erosion = pixel;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        ivec2 coord = outcoords + offsets[i];
        if (coord.x < 0 || coord.y < 0 || coord.x >= texsize.x || coord.y >= texsize.y)
            continue;
        uint val = texelFetch(samplerTex, coord, 0).x;
        erosion = min(erosion, val);
    }
    if (pixel != erosion)
        outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    else
        discard;
}
```

The problem is that textures are loaded as 256x256 tiles and `texelFetch` can't sample offsets outside of the tile boundary.
Without the `if` statement, I pick up the boundaries:

[image: Outlines with visible boundaries]

With the `if` statment the result is much better, but I am losing some information at the tile boundaries (lines are disconnected):

[image: Outlines, but imprecise]

I am not very well versed with openGL. Is there a way to sample adjacent textures? Or is there another approach to this problem?

Comment: "*Is there a way to sample adjacent textures?*" Yes: sample those textures. There is no *automatic* way to stitch together two textures into one. You must *manually* detect that you're at an edge and therefore need to sample an additional texture.

Comment: I had no idea that you can use more than one sampler in the shader program. After many hours of googling I figured out how to set them from the main program. Getting closer to a solution. Thanks!